# Adding chart title with Vincent/Vega

Tags: python, visualization, vega, vincent

I am trying to create Vega charts in python using Vincent.  Is there a way to add a title to the charts?  For some reason I cannot find any chart examples created with Vincent and/or Vega that have a chart title on top.

Here is example code from the Vincent website:

```
import vincent
vincent.core.initialize_notebook()

# dicts of iterables
cat_1 = ['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4']
index_1 = range(0, 21, 1)
multi_iter1 = {'index': index_1}
for cat in cat_1:
    multi_iter1[cat] = [random.randint(10, 100) for x in index_1]

bar = vincent.Bar(multi_iter1['y1'])
bar.axis_titles(x='Index', y='Value')
bar.width=700
bar.height=500
bar.display()
```

I have tried to do things like `bar.title="Chart Title"` without success.

Comment: I'm also looking for a built-in title feature. For now my solution is to create a text mark containing the title and put it with the chart marks within the same group so they share the space.

Answer (score 1):

Got same demand then try to find method like 'set_title' in vincent source code... and no result found.
But the 'legend' method may be an alternative of title function, like

```
bar.legend(title='test')
```